# Show related product in cart page Magento 2

Tags: magento2, cart, blocks, related-products

I want to show related product in cart page, each product at least will have 3 or more related product, is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for [Cross-sells](http://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/catalog/settings-advanced-cross-sells.html). According to official document,

> Cross-sell items are similar to impulse purchases positioned next to the cash register in the checkout line. Products offered as a cross-sell appear on the shopping cart page

You can add cross-sells following the link provided

Answer (score 0):

add in Cross-Sells items its a default option